# Menu disapear when scrolling down in bootstrap

Tags: javascript, css

In www.preciseos.com, the top menu is showing up only after you scroll down bellow the fold.
I would like to have it fixed above the fold as well and am trying to understand what trigger it to not show up above the fold. I have good understanding in JS and CSS, I just can't find what's trigger it.

Please help me understand how to have the top menu be fixed above the fold.
Thank you,
Oz

Comment: Please add your code here too. When the problem is solved, this question no longer has relevance or context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

line 16 in file /assets/js/plugins/jquery.fixedonlater.min.js is managing the top property of element id="navigation"

Answer (score 0):

If you just want a fixed menu at top there is a sticky header solution from bootstrap that is fairly straight forward:
http://getbootstrap.com/examples/starter-template/

CSS::

```
body {
  padding-top: 50px;
}
.starter-template {
  padding: 40px 15px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

HTML ::

```
 <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Project name</a>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
  </div>
</div>
```